# STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed and code coverage in XCode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, exception

I have one strange problem with XCode 4.2. Recently I decided to add code coverage support to my project which has a class named `SomeClass` with method `someMethod` which raises exception:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

- (void)someMethod;

@end


@implementation SomeClass

- (void)someMethod {  
  [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Some reason..."];
}

@end
```

The class is tested by `SomeClassTests` located in the test project which has the following method:

```
- (void)testSomeMethod {
   SomeClass *sClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];

   STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed([sClass someMethod], NSException, NSInternalInconsistencyException, @"Some description...");
}
```

So far so good - the test passes. To support code coverage I must turn on "Instrument Program Flow" and "Generate Test Coverage Files" build settings according to [this source](http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory). But when I turned on
"Instrument Program Flow" the test failed with the following error: `"raised Some reason... (Expected exception:NSException)"` 
All other tests work well. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this just by upgrading to the latest xcode.

Comment: No, I haven't. Unfortunately I was forced not to check for the exact type of the exception...

Comment: I'm just using GHAssertThrows(), which does not check type of exception.. but it still just passes exception forward instead of catching it =(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer. Repost it as a comment please.